# Sort values by lookup table using Lodash preferably

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

My data looks like this:

```
var list = [
{ name:'Charlie', age:3},
{ name:'Dog', age:1 },
{ name:'Baker', age:7},
{ name:'Abel', age:9 },
{ name:'Jim', age:5 }
];
```

I want to add a custom order e.g. not by numerical value or alphabetical. I am guessing I need to create a lookup table to accomplish my unique order/rank like below.

```
var rank = [
0: {'Abel'},
1: {'Baker'},
2: {'Jim'},
3: {'Charlie'},
4: {'Dog'}]

const name = _.sortBy(names, list=>{return list.name});
```

My `name` should `= Abel`, as I am only interested who is top. If `Abel` does not exist then `name` will bring back `Baker` etc...

I will probably need to use Lodash `sortBy`, however open to other clean solution to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a hash table with the wanted value for sorting.

For unknown names, you could add a default value and moveht these items either to top (smaller than one) or to bottom (`Infinity`).

The sort value should be different from zero, because otherwise a default value would not work, because of the falsy nature of zero.

```js
var list = [{ name: 'Charlie', age:3 }, { name: 'Dog', age: 1 }, { name: 'Baker', age: 7 }, { name: 'Abel', age: 9 }, { name: 'Jim', age: 5 }],
    rank = { Abel: 1, Baker: 2, Jim: 3, Charlie: 4, Dog: 5 },
    ordered = _.sortBy(list, ({ name }) => rank[name]);

console.log(ordered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do that is if you store your ranks in an array and then use that to fetch the sort position of the list items. This works well as it ensures you wouldn't use some odd position but you have to have each entry from `list` into `rank`.

```js
var list = [
  { name:'Charlie', age:3 },
  { name:'Dog', age:1 },
  { name:'Baker', age:7 },
  { name:'Abel', age:9 },
  { name:'Jim', age:5 }
];

var rank = [
  'Abel',
  'Baker',
  'Jim',
  'Charlie',
  'Dog'
];


var sorted = _.sortBy(list, item => rank.indexOf(item.name));

console.log(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

An alternative here is to *not* sort the array but instead generate a new array from the ranked order:

```js
var list = [
  { name:'Charlie', age:3 },
  { name:'Dog', age:1 },
  { name:'Baker', age:7 },
  { name:'Abel', age:9 },
  { name:'Jim', age:5 }
];

var rank = [
  'Abel',
  'Baker',
  'Jim',
  'Charlie',
  'Dog'
];


var sorted = _.map(rank, rankItem => _.find(list, item => item.name === rankItem));

console.log(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can also use a lookup table of ranks. This will be more efficient, as you don't need to traverse an array every time to fetch the rank - it's all pre-computed. But other than that, it's pretty much the same as the first solution:

```js
var list = [
  { name:'Charlie', age:3},
  { name:'Dog', age:1 },
  { name:'Baker', age:7},
  { name:'Abel', age:9 },
  { name:'Jim', age:5 }
];

var rank = {
  'Abel': 1,
  'Baker': 2,
  'Jim': 3,
  'Charlie': 4,
  'Dog': 5
};

var sorted = _.sortBy(list, item => rank[item.name]);

console.log(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

It should be noted that you can also do that with plain JavaScript, although it's a bit more verbose:

```js
var list = [
  { name:'Charlie', age:3 },
  { name:'Dog', age:1 },
  { name:'Baker', age:7 },
  { name:'Abel', age:9 },
  { name:'Jim', age:5 }
];

var rank = [
  'Abel',
  'Baker',
  'Jim',
  'Charlie',
  'Dog'
];

//in-place sorting
list.sort((a, b) => rank.indexOf(a.name) - rank.indexOf(b.name));
console.log(list);
```

```js
var list = [
  { name:'Charlie', age:3},
  { name:'Dog', age:1 },
  { name:'Baker', age:7},
  { name:'Abel', age:9 },
  { name:'Jim', age:5 }
];

var rank = {
  'Abel': 1,
  'Baker': 2,
  'Jim': 3,
  'Charlie': 4,
  'Dog': 5
};

//in-place sorting
list.sort((a, b) => rank[a.name] - rank[b.name]);
console.log(list);
```